# Jquery focus is not working with slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have a slick slider with caption for each image, I want to get currently focusing(using tab) caption to make some changes on it, but I can see the focus is working on the caption elements, but I can't capture it

**HTML**

```
<div class="customer-logos">
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image1.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image2.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image3.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image4.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image5.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image6.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image7.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image8.png"><a>Test</a></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.customer-logos').slick({
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 10000,
                arrows: false,
                dots: false,
                    pauseOnHover: false,
                    responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3
                    }
                }, {
                    breakpoint: 520,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2
                    }
                }]
            });
        });

    $("a").on('focus',function(e) {
    console.log($(this))
                    $(this).addClass('focused');
    });
    $("a").on('blur',function(e) {

                $(this).removeClass('focused');     
    });
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/huten0wq/498/)

Comment: you just need the text of `anchor` tag right ?

Comment: No, I want the currently focusing anchor tag objects to manipulate

Comment: It's working for me. I can get the `anchor tag` object with your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dollarsview/huten0wq/500/ check here

Comment: I can't see anything in console window

Comment: I get it. You need to click on `text` exactly. as this is where `anchor` tag is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `jquery url` you used. I used `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js` and working well.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
   pauseOnHover: false,
   responsive: [{
   breakpoint: 768,
   settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3
   }
  }, {
   breakpoint: 520,
   settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2
   }
  }]
    });
});
$("a").on('focus',function(e) {
   alert("a focus");
   $(this).addClass('focused');
});
$("a").on('blur',function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('focused');  
});
```

```css
/* Slider */
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
*.focused {
 outline-width: 2px ;
 outline-color: #282828;
 outline-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<div class="customer-logos">
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image1.png">
  <a>Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image2.png">
  <a >Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/carousel/image3.png">
  <a >Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No luck to me, still it's not working, probably it's not a solution, anyway appreciate your efforts